# É possível criar um método de função para uma variável sem adicionar no prototype no Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero converter o seguinte código abaixo para ser usado sem adicionar no prototype.

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
      return typeof args[number] != "undefined" ? args[number] : match;
    });
  };
}
```

E ele se utiliza dessa forma:

```
let name = "Nathan"
let role = "Software Developer"
let aString = "My name is {0}, I'm a {1}".format(name, role);

console.log(aString);
// My name is Nathan, I'm a Software Developer
```

E então eu gostaria de fazer algo parecido, e fiz a seguinte modificação:

```
function fvrconvert (args) {
    return this.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (match, key) {
      return typeof args[key] !== undefined ? args[key] : match;
    });
}
```

E queria usar mais ou menos assim:

```
const template = "Você acertou {qtd} de {total}";
const replacements = {qtd: "23", total: "50"};

console.log("result:", template.fvrconvert(replacements));
```

Mas provavelmente vocês que entendem mais de javascript devem saber que não funcionou.

Teria alguma forma de fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: E porque não algo como `console.log(fvrconvert(suastring, replacements))`? Não vejo motivo para ficar adicionando funções para strings em geral. De qualquer forma para afetar strings só com propototipe, você podeeria fazer assim: `function fvrconvert (args) {
    return this.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (match, key) {
      return typeof args[key] !== undefined ? args[key] : match;
    });
}` e depois `String.prototype.fvrconvert = fvrconvert;`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado por responder.  Sobre a primeira pergunta, seria para facilitar a utilização no código que estou fazendo, pois não é para uma aplicação web, é para um filtro de instagram, e vou disponibilizar os templates para outros desenvolvedores menos experientes utilizarem, e da forma que eu gostaria facilitaria o uso para eles.  Sobre o prototype é porque da forma que está sendo criado não seria uma boa opção e acho que o instagram nem aceita também.  Mas muito obrigado por tirar minhas dúvidas, vou usar como função comum mesmo, vai ser o jeito haha

Comment: Note que o prototype afeta situações como o for..in

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ah sim, obrigado por avisar. De qualquer forma não usarei mesmo o prototype. Vou seguir sua sugestão de usar como função mesmo pra não ter problemas no futuro.